# ASP.NET Core Pass form values on get

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Here is my cs page:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace CoreRazor2.Pages
{
  public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {
    [BindProperty]
    public int result { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
      if (Request.Form["+"] == true)
      {
          result = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["first"]) + Int32.Parse(Request.Form["second"]);
      }
      else if (Request.Form["-"] == true)
      {
        // code for function 2
      }
      else if (Request.Form["*"] == true)
      {

      }
      else if (Request.Form["/"] == true)
      {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my cshtml page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Calculator";
}

<form method="GET">
<label>First Value: </label>
<input name="first"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Second Value: </label>
<input name="second"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="+" value="+"/>
<input type="submit" name="-" value="-"/>
<input type="submit" name="*" value="*"/>
<input type="submit" name="/" value="/"/>
</form>
@Model.result
```

I am trying to figure out which submit gets clicked and then perform different actions depending on the button clicked. How can you do this via a get request. The code gives me an error - 'InvalidOperationException' on the first Request.Form['+'] check. How to do this properly?

Comment: Maybe it is because you're using a technology different from what i am used to, but I feel like the logic you put in your `IndexModel` should be in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MVC5, you need to this via the controller. This may work for other version, I haven't tested (and I am not sure which technology you actually use)

Give the same name to all your submit buttons, it is the value that you will get as a parameter

```
// Update your HTML as follow
<input type = "submit" name = "operationType" value = "+"/>
<input type = "submit" name = "operationType" value = "-"/>
<input type = "submit" name = "operationType" value = "*"/>
<input type = "submit" name = "operationType" value = "/"/>
```

and change your controller to have a "operationType" argument as follow

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string operationType)
{
    int result = 0;
    switch(operationType)
    {
        case "+":
            result = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["first"]) + Int32.Parse(Request.Form["second"]);
            break;
        case "-":
            break;
        case "/":
            break;
        case "*":
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the asp-page-handler 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio

example

```
<input type="submit" asp-page-handler="JoinList" value="Join" />
<input type="submit" asp-page-handler="JoinListUC" value="JOIN UC" />

 public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostJoinListAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _db.Customers.Add(Customer);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostJoinListUCAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            Customer.Name = Customer.Name?.ToUpper();
            return await OnPostJoinListAsync();
        }
```